# How to change cell value in table on click?

Tags: javascript, php, html

My assignment is to create a multiplication table with numbers from 1 to 10 which has all possible combinations of those numbers and when clicked on one of the possibilities it should change cell and output the result.
For example, when you click on 2 x 4, cell changes to 8.
When clicked it is also supposed to send data to database, including two factors, result and date when cell was clicked.

I have managed to create a table and tried to add onclick event on cells, like shown in the code, but that doesn't work. Is it even possible to do that in php or do I need to include javascript?

```
<html>
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
function changeCell($row,$col){
    echo $row*$col;
}
?>
<table table border =\"1\" style='border-collapse: collapse'  class='style'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <?php for($j=1;$j<=10;$j++)
            {
                ?>
            <th><?php echo $j; ?></th>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
        <?php 
        for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++)
        { echo "<tr> \n";
        ?>
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
        <?php
            for ($j=1;$j<=10;$j++)
            {
        ?>
            <td onclick = 'changeCell($i,$j)'><?php echo $i." x ".$j; ?></td>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use PHP to receive the data from the browser and store in the database. Use JavaScript in the browser to interact with the end user and change the table. You are on the right track with onclick, you just need to implement that in JavaScript.

Comment: PHP runs on the server and has finished when the page has loaded. To achieve what you use javascript

Comment: Here is some help for the click event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick#Examples, and you'll want to become familiar with a method for sending your result and date back to the server. So read up on using AJAX for doing that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data

Answer (score 0):

A simple demo to illustrate event handling and using ajax to send info to the db / backend.

As mentioned in the above comment: PHP runs at the server and will have finished performing all of it's tasks before the browser finally loads the page so any PHP function you are hoping to execute in response to a user action needs to be triggered in another thread. This is most commonly achieved using ajax/fetch.

```
<?php
    /* set size of table */
    $rows = $columns = 12;


    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        $_POST['db']='updated';
        exit( json_encode( $_POST ) );
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{

                /* a rudimentary ajax function for performing POST requests */
                const ajax=function(url,params,callback){
                    let xhr=new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onload=function(){
                        if( this.status==200 && this.readyState==4 )callback.call( this, this.response )
                    };
                    xhr.onerror=function(e){
                        alert(e)
                    };
                    xhr.open( 'POST', url, true );
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With','XMLHttpRequest');
                    xhr.send( params );
                };

                /* A very basic callback function */
                const ajaxcallback=function(r){
                    document.querySelector('output').innerText=r
                }

                /*
                    scan the DOM to find all table cell elements with assigned class "multiplication"
                    and assign an event listener to each.

                    The event listener listens for clicks, captures certain dataset attributes from the
                    event target ( cell ) and performs the calculation using the numbers found.

                    The ajax function sends a querystring to the backend PHP script for processing - that
                    part has not been done here.

                    The clicked table cell will reflect the answer temporarily before reverting to it's original
                    value.
                */
                Array.prototype.slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('table td.multiplication') ).forEach( cell=>{
                    cell.addEventListener('click',function(e){

                        let challenge=this.innerText;
                        let product=this.dataset.row * this.dataset.column;

                        ajax.call( this, location.href, 'task=multiplication&challenge='+challenge+'&a='+this.dataset.row+'&b='+this.dataset.column+'&product='+product, ajaxcallback )

                        console.info( 'Challenge: %s Row: %s Column: %s Answer: %d',challenge, this.dataset.row, this.dataset.column, product );

                        this.innerText=product;
                        this.classList.add('product');

                        setTimeout( function(e){
                            this.innerText=challenge;
                            this.classList.remove('product');
                        }.bind( cell ), 2500 );
                    })
                })
            });
        </script>
        <style>
            body, body *{box-sizing:border-box;font-size:0.9rem;font-family:calibri,verdana,arial}
            body{padding:0;margin:0;}
            table{background:azure;}
            table{width:80%;height:80vh;border:1px solid black;float:none;margin:auto;}
            td{text-align:center;margin:1px;background:white}
            td.multiplication{border:1px dotted gray;cursor:pointer;}
            th,td.rowheader{background:gray;color:white;}
            .product{background:rgba(0,255,0,0.1)}
            output{display:block;float:none;margin:auto;width:80%;padding:0.5rem;text-align:center; color:red }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                <?php
                    for( $i=0; $i <= $columns+1; $i++ ){
                        if( $i > 0 )printf("<th scope='col' data-column=%d>%d</th>", $i-1, $i-1 );
                    }
                ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    for( $i=1; $i <= $rows; $i++ ){
                        echo "<tr data-row=$i>";

                        for( $j=0; $j <= $columns; $j++ ){
                            if( $j > 0 )printf("<td class='multiplication' data-row=%d data-column=%d>%d x %d</td>",$i,$j,$i,$j);
                            else printf("<td class='rowheader'>$i</td>");
                        }

                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                ?>
            </table>
            <output></output>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I honestly don't understand half of it. I am very new to this, I am supposed to have separate php and html file which contains table, than one php with class with operations done and javascript one. I have tried to write separate js file with onclick function, but couldn't make it work in my php file. My plan was to write that first, and than focus on database part.

Comment: take the javascript - copy to a new file and include in the HTML page using standard script tag with src attribute. Similar for the CSS - new file and include using link tag with href attribute. The PHP code at the top does nothing useful - that can easily be a different page sp change `location.href` in the javascript to whatever url you decide. Did you copy all the above and create new page to try this by any chance?